# what's the best way to store same hash field in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I store user-feeds in redis, every feed is stored as a hash and the key is the users ID, the field of the hash is user that created the content and the value is the content, how do I handle a case where the content-creator makes multiple posts, because it would overwrite what's in cache already and not store the new content.

Comment: Hello & welcome, do you mean similar hash key  or same hash field ?

Comment: Sorry, same hash field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "mostly" depends on how do you want to query it. If you are going to get all hash fields/values at once(`HGETALL`) then you may append timestamp next to your identifier;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:1:feed user:2:1591081521 content1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:1:feed user:2:1591081532 yet-another-content
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:1:feed user:3:1591081543 super-content
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall user:1:feed
1) "user:2:1591081521"
2) "content1"
3) "user:2:1591081532"
4) "yet-another-content"
5) "user:3:1591081543"
6) "super-content"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If there is possibility to save multiple content at the same time(scheduling multiple content to be released at a certain time) then you may append some random string too.

If you are not getting all the contents of user but feed of a user displaying only the contents of a specific user then you may use sorted set. In this example `score` is the user id of the content owner and you can query them via using `ZRANGEBYSCORE`. You can still get all the contents of user:1 with `ZRANGE`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user:1:feed 2 content
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user:1:feed 2 content-another
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user:1:feed 2 content-another-some-another
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE user:1:feed 2 2 withscores
1) "content"
2) "2"
3) "content-another"
4) "2"
5) "content-another-some-another"
6) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user:1:feed 3 content-of-user-3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange user:1:feed 0 -1 withscores
1) "content"
2) "2"
3) "content-another"
4) "2"
5) "content-another-some-another"
6) "2"
7) "content-of-user-3"
8) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```